# Why do I get a 404 error when curling into Kie Server after deploying a project in Red Hat Decision Manager?

Tags: curl, http-status-code-404, redhat, redhat-containers, redhat-decision-manager

I am trying to curl into Kie Server after deploying a project in Red Hat Decision Manager.

I have followed the instructions at [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.11/html-single/deploying_and_managing_red_hat_decision_manager_services/index#kie-server-configure-central-proc_packaging-deploying), including the configuration of the standalone-full.xml file.

After deploying a project, I can see it listed under Deployment Units on the Execution Servers page of Business Central.

When I run the following in the Mac terminal, as instructed by the decision manager guide (link above):

```
curl http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server
```

I get the respone:

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>404 - Not Found</body></html>
```

I was expecting to get the following response as per the Decision Manager documentation:

```
<response type="SUCCESS" msg="Kie Server info">
    <kie-server-info>
        <capabilities>KieServer</capabilities>
        <capabilities>BRM</capabilities>
        <capabilities>BPM</capabilities>
        <capabilities>CaseMgmt</capabilities>
        <capabilities>BPM-UI</capabilities>
        <capabilities>BRP</capabilities>
        <capabilities>DMN</capabilities>
        <capabilities>Swagger</capabilities>
        <location>http://localhost:8230/kie-server/services/rest/server</location>
        <messages>
            <content>Server KieServerInfo{serverId='first-kie-server', version='7.5.1.Final-redhat-1', location='http://localhost:8230/kie-server/services/rest/server', capabilities=[KieServer, BRM, BPM, CaseMgmt, BPM-UI, BRP, DMN, Swagger]}started successfully at Mon Feb 05 15:44:35 AEST 2018</content>
            <severity>INFO</severity>
            <timestamp>2018-02-05T15:44:35.355+10:00</timestamp>
        </messages>
        <name>first-kie-server</name>
        <id>first-kie-server</id>
        <version>7.5.1.Final-redhat-1</version>
    </kie-server-info>
</response>
```

Comment: Do you have some error messages on the application server log ?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to follow the paths from the manual.
`/kie-server/services/rest/server/` and
`/kie-server/services/rest/server` are different paths. The first one is interpreted as a wrong path w/o an object. The second one is a correct path to the object `server`.

Run this command as for **Table 2.1. JVM Properties for the managed KIE Server instance**, the bottommost row:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server
```

Comment: I tried both with and without the slash. Still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the request port number from 8080 to 8180, I was running a kie server from docker, which mapped the port to 8180 at runtime, and changed it to be accessible